# AJAX replace breaks dropdown - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a functional dropdown:

```
    <li data-dropdown="publish-dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" id="publish">
        Publish
        <img alt="" border="0" src="/assets/publish-arrow.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
```

And the elements for this dropdown are(HAML):

```
  .home-dropdown-menu.publish-dropdown-menu#publish-dropdown-menu
    .top-arrow
    %a.your-services{:href => new_service_path}
      .icon-drop
      %span
        Your
        %br>/
        Service
    %a.your-event{:href => new_event_path}
      .icon-drop
      %span
        Your
        %br>/
        EVENT
```

But when this is replaced by AJAX this won't work anymore.

This is what I tried:

```
$('#publish').dropdown()
$('#publish').parent().dropdown()
```

But none of these worked.

Any advice on how to reset dropdown behaviour after page has been loaded.

## Update

This is how I am replacing content:

```
$('#header').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/header') %>')
```

Header has a lot of other content so is not easy for me to replace some parts.

Comment: How are you replacing the content of the dropdown, can you post that code?

Comment: all HTML HAML code I posted is being replaced from its parent. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown` function or any events which were attached when DOM was loaded for the first time does not work for newly added elements.  You need to reattach any events that were initially attached and re-call functions that you had called on those elements.

The reattachment of events can be achieved using [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, but as `dropdown` is not an event and is a function we need to implement something like the following:

Trigger an event e.g. 'show' where you update the content of `#header` like follows:

```
$('#header').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/header') %>").trigger('show');
```

Then call `dropdown` on the element in the `show` event handler in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('show', '#header', function() {
        $('#publish').dropdown();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I tried `$('#publish').dropdown();` in console, after AJAX replacement, this is equivalent, right?